# Why using alignof on non-typed types is valid?

Tags: c++, eigen, alignof

The data shows that alignof is used `type-id`, but why I can use `Eigen::Matrix4f` like below.

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix4f t_localizer = ndt.getFinalTransformation();
std::cout << "t_localizer alignof: " << alignof(t_localizer);  // ??
std::cout << "t_localizer alignof: " << alignof(Eigen::Matrix4f); // valid
```

Both codes can compile and work!

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Is there some information or code to explain?

Comment: Allowing `alignof t_localizer` (braces are optional) is a gnu-extension. If you compile with `-Wpedantic` you get a warning: https://godbolt.org/z/jd9sxK96e

Comment: This is probably to allow the same syntax as `sizeof` (not sure why this is not allowed by the standard, though).